# Communicating with the web server using Google Home

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I have a social networking website developed in php which is hosted on the server. Here people can talk to each other through messages.

I want to send and receive the messages, to the other users through google home. It is not like a chat bot. But here, the first user will send message from google home to the website and then the second user will send the message from the website to the first user who will receive it through google home.

Can this be achieved? Do I have to develop some kind of mobile App, so that user has to send the message to the mobile app and then the app sends the data to the server.

or do i have to use the webhook which is available in api.ai?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a mobile app - it sounds like most (but not all) of what you're trying to do would be handled using API.AI's webhook Fulfillment.

However, you're also trying to do asynchronous operations (send a message or a notification to Home without the user prompting for it). This currently isn't possible - you can currently only send a message in response to the user taking some action.

One possible workaround for you is to allow the user to ask "how many messages are waiting for me" or something similar at any point. You can also play multiple messages in reply to a message they might send. However, you have limits (about 5 seconds) on how long you can wait to send a reply to a user instruction.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a chat bot e.g. via Dialogflow (former api.ai), however you can just react on inputs. You cannot *push* a message on Google Home (yet). So you could the bot read your mailbox but not implement a chat.

Comment: and will this "react on inputs" be achieved only using webhooks?

Comment: I mean you can just response on (voice) inputs. The only way to get then data from your backend is to use that webhooks. So yes.